# IOS UITableView Selection Highlight is sometimes very quick and did select is not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection

Have a strange issue where about 15% of the time, when selecting a cell with a UITableView the cell highlight flashes quickly and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called.  The rest of the time it is working fine.

Tested how it was being selected (fast / slow finger nail, etc), but this does not seem to be the case.  Looks semi-random.

Any thoughts one what might be causing this?

IOS 6.x

[Addition]
Thanks for the comments so far.

If while clicking the mouse (simulator) is moving, the problem can be duplicated.  Even if the table is set to .scrollEnabled = false it is still happening.  Also, the didHighlightRowAtIndexPath does fire and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not in the "quick" case.

Same thing happens on IOS 5.x also...

[Conclusion]

Well, it turns out that the scrolling was turned off for the table and it seems to be even more picky with the "moving tap"  Turning the scrolling on actually made the "moving tap" less picky.  There were a couple of other postings that I just found that pretty much said the same thing.  This is a strange conclusion for a table view that has scrolling disabled and produces a "quick highlight" with no selection.  Looks like this is why they added the didHighlight in IOS 6 to try and get around this "issue".

Comment: I had this exact issue trying to put a UITableView in a UIScrollView on iOS 6.  Is your table view in a UIScrollView class?

Comment: Don't think so but will check it out.  This is a larger app

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that a view from with in the cell is absorbing the touch rather than the cell ? 
maybe you have a gesture recognizer in the cell, those take priorities over simple touch events

Comment: Nope, no gesture in the cell / custom cell.  Looked at all of the gestures in the project and none seem to be a parent.  Will look again

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason your cell is disabled. Try setting `cell.enabled = TRUE;` right before the cell is displayed and see if it fixes anything.

Comment: Nope, cell is properly enabled, etc

Answer (score 0):

You're moving your finger up or down slightly, causing the table to scroll. Your item will not be selected, and the highlight will disappear. I've dealt with this before by tracking the row in tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath, and then doing the action in tableView:didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath: . You might also be able to solve your problem by making the tableView not scrollable if that's an option in your ui.

Comment: This seems like what is happening.  Have disabled scrolling on the table with no change.  Could do DidHighlight, but will have to support IOS 5.x also and it does not have this.